# Rails how to get gem version in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Do you know how to show in my application the version of gem?
I don't need a rake task, I want to show the version in admin page.

Like e.g. "Gem::Version('bundler')"

Answer (score 7):

You would use the following:

```
bundler_version = Gem.loaded_specs['bundler'].version
#=> Gem::Version.new("1.6.2")
```

The Gem::Version's string representation is just the version number.

```
puts bundler_version
# 1.6.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have another one:

```
Gemname::VERSION::STRING
```

Example:

```
puts Rails::VERSION::STRING
#4.1.1
```

Comment: Your answer suggests using Gemname::VERSION which assumes that all gems have a constant called VERSION. While many gems do this, not all do. For example, Puma does not have a constant for Puma::VERSION

Comment: You are right. Was my fault not mention this detail :D

Answer (score -2):

```
gem -v
```

or

```
--version
```

or you can simply in command prompt write `gem -help` and it will show you how

Comment: Not the answer to what was asked. OP does not want to know the version of Rubygems itself, but programmatically access the version of gems installed through Bundler.